# Does user search query support OR clause for Orgunits?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm trying to use the google directory api to get a specific set of users  based on their orgUnitPath. I can't seem to get a query working where I do something like `orgUnitPath=/OUTest OR orgUnitPath=/LeftOU` without having to make two separate api calls. Any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query does not support OR. Currently two API calls will be necessary.

Comment: Is it possible now ?